# blogspot.com on another domain

Tags: dns, blogspot

i have blogspot blog and i want to change the domain name `www.xyz.blogspot.com` to my domain `www.xyz.com`
i [register](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs) my domain but now when i go to my blog i have this error

> Directory has no index file.
>
> Browsing this site or directory without an index file is prohibited.
>   If you are the site's webmaster, you can remedy this problem by
>   creating a default HTML page with one of the following names:
>
> index.html index.htm default.htm Default.htm home.html Home.chtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your domain, you should be able to modify what it points to. You should be able to select CNAME and then write in the `www.xyz.blogspot.com`. This will basically link your domain to your `www.xyz.blogspot.com` site and users will only see `www.xyz.com`.

Another solution is to add index.php that looks like this:

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://www.xyz.blogspot.com");
?>
```

But this will only redirect the user to the old page and thus it will show `http://www.xyz.blogspot.com` in the address-bar.

Comment: thanks simon i will try to modify the CNAME to `www.xyz.blogspot.com`

Comment: @tito11 Don't forget to vote up and accept the answer if it helped.